# Android Studio - unable to select data in Android network profiler

Tags: android-studio

I used to be able to select data from the graph of the Android Network Profiler but it stop working for some reason. Now when I try to click and drag to select data, nothing, the cursor doesn't change and I can't select anything. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue3dY.png

Answer (score 4):

The Advanced Profiler was disabled. Issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Rerun project solve the problem for me