# Android Studio Network Profiler : impossible to select a range on the network activity graph

Tags: java, android, android-studio, profiler, android-profiler

I am trying to use to use the network profiler but I am unable to select a portion of the graph in order to see the content of the network packets.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235877/android-studio-unable-to-select-data-in-android-network-profiler) and I activated the advanced profiling but as expected it changed nothing (as advanced profiling seems to be required only below API 26 ; my device is with API 29.

Do you see how to solve this problem ?

Thanks !

**EDIT:** it seems that there is a kind of bug in Android Profiler: sometimes I can select a range and sometimes I can't ; any solution to remove this bug?

Comment: did u got solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to my own question: it seems that the Network Profiler doesn't allow to select a range in order to see the connections when the app is executed in Android 10 emulator or device. I ran on Android 7 emulator and device and it works fine if you additionally activate 'Advanced profiling' in the Edit configuration menu of your target. Works perhaps also on Android 8 and 9, not yet tested.

Comment: @tot_tata any solution to test battery in android 11 phone